# Django, mod_wsgi, psycopg2 ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named _psycopg

Tags: django, apache, postgresql, psycopg2, centos6

I have a Django 1.5, Python 2.7 site running  under Apache with mod_wsgi on a CentOS 6.4 server.

I have rebuilt this site using Django 1.6 and Python 3.3. Deploying it to the same server and changing the paths in httpd.conf I get the subject error. This new install works as expected using ./manage.py runserver.

Here are the two WSGI definitions from httpd.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ccdgen/CCDGEN2/apache/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath         /home/ccdgen/CCDGEN2/ccdgen/ccdgen:/home/ccdgen/CCDGEN2/ccdgen:/home/ccdgen/CCDGEN2/lib/python3.3/site-packages
<Directory /home/ccdgen/CCDGEN2/ccdgen>
   <Files wsgi.py>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
   </Files>
</Directory>

#WSGIScriptAlias /ccdgen /home/ccdgen/CCDGEN/apache/wsgi.py
#WSGIPythonPath /home/ccdgen/CCDGEN/mlhim/ccdgen:/home/ccdgen/CCDGEN/mlhim:/home/ccdgen/CCDGEN/lib/python2.7/site-packages
#<Directory /home/ccdgen/CCDGEN/mlhim>
#   <Files wsgi.py>
#     Order allow,deny
#     Allow from all
#   </Files>
#</Directory>
```

The wsgi.py file is the same on both installations:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mlhim.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any ideas?  Obvious oversights?  Thanks

Comment: Sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2 or whatever is centos version of installing packages...

Comment: Thanks but obviously it I have already installed it.  It works with the previous site as well as when I run the Django dev server.

Comment: There are more solutions on this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42004986/4794).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that mod_wsgi was compiled for Python 2.7 and it needed to be recompiled for Python 3.3.  I did not find a new mod_wsgi available anywhere as a package so I recompiled it.

Since Python 3 is an alternate install on CentOS 6.4  .configure had a difficult time producing a good Makefile, even passing the --with-python  option.  I needed to edit Makefile a bit after getting the information from  python3.3-config --cflags   and also with  --ldflags  options.

HTH someone in the future.

Comment: Can you plz explain what exactly did you do?

Comment: It was over a year ago so I do not recall the step by step process.  But you will need to recompile Python on CentOS and read up on cflags and ldflags because the Makefile needs to be edited.  I eventually moved the DB that requires CentOS/RHE to the cloud and went back to Ubuntu Server for my Django app.  IMO, modern Python on development and use on CentOS is a no go.

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem recently:

`ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named _psycopg`

... and this command was the answer:

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`

Reference:

http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/ImproperlyConfigured-Error-loading-psycopg2-module-No-module-named-psycopg-td5044145.html

Answer (score 4):

**Try these commands  Debian, Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

**For  RedHat Enterprise, Fedora, CentOS**

```
sudo yum install python-devel
sudo yum install postgresql-libs
```

**Then Install psycopg2**

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: As above; it is already installed. The Django dev server works.  Also, running ./manage.py shell then import psycopg2 works. As well as :  from psycopg2 import _psycopg

Comment: are you using python virtualenv for running both way or not ?

Comment: Yes, the previous site was running under a python 2.7 virtualenv and the new one is installed under a python 3.3 virtualenv.

Comment: Can you try this one: yum install  python33-python-psycopg2 and 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', may be this work

Comment: After attempting to break out of dependency hell I am in a circle. Error: Package: python33-python-3.3.2-7.el6.x86_64 (/python33-python-3.3.2-7.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: python33-python-libs(x86-64) = 3.3.2-7.el6   andError: Package: python33-python-libs-3.3.2-7.el6.x86_64 (/python33-python-libs-3.3.2-7.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: python33-python(abi) = 3.3
 Where python33-python(abi) is provided by     python33-python-3.3.2-7.el6.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Recompiling mod_wsgi with python3.3 and editing the Makefile using flags from python3.3-config --cflags and then with --ldflags; has at least changed the problem to one of a URLs config issue. So I won't call it resolved yet.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, mod_wsgi has not been compiled for python 3. One option is to use [Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/) and/or go with nginx, and "pip install uwsgi" which saves a lot of compiling and running custom packages.