# python3 - ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, ubuntu-16.04

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Logic/model.py", line 12, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 66, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'
```

I don't have PIL installed but I have pillow installed
what to do?

Comment: How did you install it? pip? this might be related to a mod_wsgi issue please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661508/error-with-compiled-pillow-on-python-3-6-virtualenv/43671174#43671174

Comment: Does this work? `from PIL.Image import core as _imaging`