# The Python Pillow package works from the command line but not over Apache/WSGI

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, mod-wsgi

When I run this in the terminal it imports without an error:

`from PIL import Image`

When I run the same code in my Flask app running over Apache/WSGI, it causes an error:

`cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/var/www/app/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)`

I installed `Pillow` into the virtual environment correctly. I did *not* install the older PIL package and have checked a dozen times to make sure it's not installed and causing a conflict.

I installed WSGI for Python 3 like this:

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`

EVERYTHING about the app, including all other Python modules/dependencies has been running just fine for months. `Pillow` is the only one that doesn't work in the deployed app, but does work when run from the terminal.

My Apache configuration file includes this reference to the virtual environment location:

`WSGIPythonHome "/var/www/app/env"`

I've tried older versions of `Pillow` with no success. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling `Pillow`. I've tried nuking my virtual environment and creating it again from scratch. Kind of at a loss here.

Comment: You cannot install `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` not for system python of specific version for which it was compiled. DIY

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install & configure mod\_wsgi for py3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344252/how-to-install-configure-mod-wsgi-for-py3)

Comment: Are you saying that `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` cannot be used if you have a specific version of Python that is NOT the system version of Python?

Either way, I solved the issue by uninstalling `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` and used `pip install mod_wsgi` within my virtual env. Then I moved the mod_wsgi.so file it created into my Apache `modules` directory and edited `mods-available/wsgi.load` to include a path to the .so file.

This is the specific answer that SOLVED it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661508/error-with-compiled-pillow-on-python-3-6-virtualenv/43671174#43671174

Comment: Yes, exactly: `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` cannot be used for custom python installations or venv's. It may occasionally work, but is unreliable, at least.

Comment: Good to know, thank you! Learned this lesson the hard way 

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by uninstalling `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` and using `pip install mod_wsgi` inside my virtual environment instead.

I followed this particular answer specifically: [Error with compiled Pillow on Python 3.6 virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661508/error-with-compiled-pillow-on-python-3-6-virtualenv/43671174#43671174)