# Django - Apache2 - Postgresql: error with _psycopg

Tags: django, apache, postgresql, wsgi

Trying to deploy a django project on apache (2.2) on Debian 7.
Using Django 1.8 and a virtual environment with python3.4.

Getting the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named _psycop

I have tried the suggestions pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158918/django-mod-wsgi-psycopg2-improperlyconfigured-error-loading-psycopg2-module), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728004/error-no-module-named-psycopg2-extensions).

Here is my apache conf.

(following lines are nested within VirtualHost scope)

`#WSGI configuration for ds_monitor django project`

```
Alias /static /home/pkaramol/Applications/timeds/ds_monitor/static_root
<Directory /home/pkaramol/Applications/timeds/ds_monitor/static_root>
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /home/pkaramol/Applications/timeds/ds_monitor/ds_monitor>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Allow from all
   </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess ds_monitor python-path=/home/pkaramol/Applications/timeds/ds_monitor:/home/pkaramol/Applications/timeds/venv_p34dj18/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup ds_monitor
WSGIScriptAlias /ds_monitor  /home/pkaramol/Applications/timeds/ds_monitor/ds_monitor/wsgi.py
```

and this outside VirtualHost scope (to enable production - time virtual environment)

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/pkaramol/Applications/timeds/ds_monitor:/home/pkaramol/Applications/timeds/venv_p34dj18/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

Another issue is the following line present in apache's log stack trace

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 821, in _gcd_import
    loader.load_module(name)
```

Why is it using system's python 3.2?

Have I done s.th wrong in terms of pointing the virtualenv path correctly in wsgi confs?

In any case, the `psycopg2` module is also installed in the system (not only in virtualenv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems very weird but the whole issue most likely had to do with the python version that `mod_wsgi` was compiled against.

I had downloaded / configured / installed version 4.5.2 of mod_wsgi from [here](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases) but forgot to configure with the appropriate python version.

So I run through the whole process again (starting from unzipping the original tarball) and configuring as follows:

`./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.5`

Restarted apache and problem solved.