# 500 Error when starting Django on Apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, postgresql, mod-wsgi

I'm getting 500 error while trying to start Django (1.10.5) on Apache (with mod_wsgi) using **postgre** DB. The installation dependencies are django and. **psycopg2**. They are installed on a **Python 3.6** virtual environment.

**Hint:** Everything works fine, when I try to start the virtual environment via "**python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000**" but when I try to reach the :80 port on apache the following error is listed in /var/log/httpd/error_log

```
Handling WSGI exception 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/djangotest/djangotest/wsgi.py", line 40, in <module> application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application django.setup(set_prefix=False)
File "/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module __import__(name)
File "/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module> from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
File "/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module> class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
File "/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 119, in __new__ new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
File "/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in add_to_class value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
File "/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__ return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__ backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module __import__(name)
File "/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 24, in <module> raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named _psycopg [remote 88.AAA.BBB.CC:76] mod_wsgi (pid=18487): Target WSGI script '/root/djangotest/djangotest/wsgi.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
```

The content of /etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf :

```
Alias /static /root/djangotest/static

WSGIScriptAlias / /root/djangotest/djangotest/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /root/djangotest:/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages

<Directory /root/djangotest/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /root/djangotest/djangotest>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess djangotest python-path=/root/djangotest:/root/djangotest/djangotestvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup djangotest
```

The content of wsgi.py :

```
import os
import time
import traceback
import signal
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'djangotest.settings'

try:
    application = get_wsgi_application()
    print("WSGI without exception")
except Exception:
    print("handling WSGI exception")
    # Error loading applications
    if 'mod_wsgi' in sys.modules:
        traceback.print_exc()
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
        time.sleep(2.5)
```

Although the psycopg2 is installed on venv succesfully and works fine, it throws error when trying to reach: 80 via with apache & mod_wsgi.

Thank you.

Comment: can you load your wsgi.py?

Comment: Did you try solutions provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21158918/5616580  ?

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov I have loaded the content of wsgi.py

Comment: @mateuszb what might be an equivalent of libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 on CentOS7.3?

Comment: @Phyticist Unfortunately I don't know the CentOS's equivalent of this package

Comment: How did you install Python 3.6. It is unlikely system mod_wsgi package is for Python 3.6 and so you can't use mod_wsgi with a virtual environment for Python 3.6. See warnings about virtual environments and Python versions in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thank you so much, with the help of the info you've provided I've left python 3.6 and installed 3.5 then compiled mod_wsgi with python3.5. Now everything works in my 3.5 venv as expected.